# How to iterate List of object array and set to another object list in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Currently I have list of object array from that array i have to Iterate and add to the list of my `LatestNewsDTO` what i have done below code working but still i am not satisfy with my way . Is their any efficient way please let me know.

Thanks

```
List<Object[]> latestNewses = latestNewsService.getTopNRecords(companyId, false, 3);
List<LatestNewsDTO> latestNewsList = new ArrayList();
latestNewses.forEach(objects -> {
    LatestNewsDTO latestNews = new LatestNewsDTO();
    latestNews.setId(((BigInteger) objects[0]).intValue());
    latestNews.setCreatedOn((Date) objects[1]);
    latestNews.setHeadLine((String) objects[2]);
    latestNews.setContent(((Object) objects[3]).toString());
    latestNews.setType((String) objects[4]);
    latestNewsList.add(latestNews); 
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a `Stream` to map your `Object[]` arrays to `LatestNewsDTO`s and collect them into a `List` :

```
List<LatestNewsDTO> latestNewsList =
    latestNewses.stream()
                .map(objects -> {
                    LatestNewsDTO latestNews = new LatestNewsDTO();
                    latestNews.setId(((BigInteger) objects[0]).intValue());
                    latestNews.setCreatedOn((Date) objects[1]);
                    latestNews.setHeadLine((String) objects[2]);
                    latestNews.setContent(((Object) objects[3]).toString());
                    latestNews.setType((String) objects[4]);
                    return latestNews;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, if you create a constructor of `LatestNewsDTO` that accepts the the array, the code will look more elegant.

```
List<LatestNewsDTO> latestNewsList =
    latestNewses.stream()
                .map(objects -> new LatestNewsDTO(objects))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now the `LatestNewsDTO (Object[] objects)` constructor can hold the logic that parses the array and sets the members of your instance.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will go for second approach which look very elegant.

Comment: You can even do `.map(LatestNewsDTO::new)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks Your approach also look nice.I have learned something today

Answer (score 0):

As per the Peter Lawrey comments, This way also looks great even though i have accept the Eran answer.

I have Created the constructor with objects

```
 public LatestNewsDTO(Object[] objects) {
      /**set all members instance 
    }
```

And I did like this

```
 List<Object[]> latestNewses = latestNewsService.getAllRecords(companyId, false);

        List<LatestNewsDTO> latestNewsList = latestNewses.stream()
                .map(LatestNewsDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```