# How to convert the following Stream to a Pojo

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Data representation is as below

dept | count | name

a    |    5  | Ramesh

a    |    2  | Alok

b    |    4  | Suresh

b    |    5  | Arnold

c    |    4  | Brian

c    |    5  | Santosh

c    |    5  | Ramesh

I want to convert the below list

```
List<Object[]> departWiseDistinctNameCount = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a", "5", "Ramesh"), Arrays.asList("a", "2", "Alok"), Arrays.asList("b", "4", "Suresh"), Arrays.asList("b", "5", "Arnold"), Arrays.asList("c", "4", "Brian"), Arrays.asList("c", "5", "Santosh"), Arrays.asList("c", "5", "Ramesh"));
```

To POJO

```
   class Dept {
    private String deptName;
    List<Counter> counters;
  }

    class Counter{
       private int count;
       private String name;
  }
```

Comment: why is it like this: Arrays.asList("a", "5", "Ramesh"), why don't you build it as the pojo in the first place? You can use the map functionality of streams to do what you want.

Comment: I am fetching it from the database so it is in a row format

Comment: ok? and why don't you just fetch it as a list of POJO's directly, instead of mapping them later on?

Comment: Have you look at my question but its for list ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790723/how-to-iterate-list-of-object-array-and-set-to-another-object-list-in-java-8

Comment: @soorapadman he can easily read his data directly to the desired type from his DB. The 'afterwards mapping' is redundant.

Comment: @Stultuske I agreed you 100% .

Comment: @Stultuske  how can I map the resultSet to my POJO?

Comment: @PRO_G don't. make sure your ResultSet gets it as a List of your POJO's. I would recommend some basic courses on JPA/Hibernate to get you started

Comment: ok. but how can I directly map the query response to a POJO

Comment: also one dept has multiple count isnt that also has to be a list . I suspect there is something wrong with the Data or the table, plesae check once.

Comment: count column tells the number of person in the department which has same name as in the third column

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been pointed out in the comments, you should definitely try to fetch the data as a list of POJOs directly.

However, you asked for a way to map the list, so here you go:

```java
departWiseDistinctNameCount.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0),
                    Collectors.mapping(l -> new Counter(Integer.parseInt(l.get(1)), l.get(2)),
                            Collectors.toList())))
            .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new Dept(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

For clarification: I added the constructors `public Dept(String deptName, List<Counter> counters)` and `public Counter(int count, String name)`.

Also, your statement for declaring `departWiseDistinctNameCount` does in fact cause an compilation error as a `List<List<String>>` cannot be casted to a `List<Object[]>`. I assumed a `List<List<String>>`, but if you only have the latter you can easily cast within the stream by using `(String) l[0]` instead of `l.get(0)` etc.