# Iterate over list in Java

Tags: java

I have one file with a few classes like below:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class GlobalDto {
    List<SomeClass> someClass;
}

@Getter @Setter
class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
}
```

How can I iterate over this `List<SomeClass> someClass;` in a for-each loop?

I tried this:

```
List<GlobalDto> list;
for(GlobalDto item : list) {
       List<SomeClass > it = item.getSomeClass().get(0);
}
```

However, my IntelliJ throw an *incompatible types* error, and want from a many casting. So, how to get from my `GlobalDto` an `lastName` from `SomeClass`?

Comment: If your list is `List<GlobalDto> list;` then your loop should work (at least based on what you are showing). If it doesn't then `incopatibble types` should give you more details about nature of the problem compiler sees and complains about. Use [edit] option to include actual error message and [mcve].

Comment: Take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790723/how-to-iterate-list-of-object-array-and-set-to-another-object-list-in-java-8

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this: You say that `it` is `List<SomeClass>`, but `item.getSomeClass().get0` returns `someClass` object, that's why `it` and the return value of method you are calling are *incompatible types*.

```
List<GlobalDto> list;
for(GlobalDto item : list) {
   List<SomeClass> it = item.getSomeClass().get(0); 
   // it = List, items.getSomeClass() returns List, but items.getSomeClass().get(0) returns SomeClass object
}
```

If you want to iterate the `List` of `SomeClass` object to get or set their names, just do this:

```
List<GlobalDto> list;
for(GlobalDto item : list) {
   List<SomeClass> it = item.getSomeClass(); // get the list
   for(SomeClass some : it) {
       // do whatever
   }
}
```